Add attachment in node imap
I'm using node imap :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-imap

i have this method to save message as draft
 imap.once('ready', () => {
      imap.openBox('Drafts', false, (err, box) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let msg, htmlEntity, plainEntity;
        msg = mimemessage.factory({
          contentType: 'multipart/alternate',
          body: []
        });
        htmlEntity = mimemessage.factory({
          contentType: 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
          body: 'Draft Mail'
        });
        plainEntity = mimemessage.factory({
          body: 'Draft Mail'
        });
        msg.header('Message-ID', '<msgId>');
        msg.header('To','email@domain.com');
        msg.header('Subject', 'Mail');
        msg.body.push(plainEntity);
        msg.body.push(htmlEntity);
        imap.append(msg.toString());
      })
    });

I want to add attachment also in this mail and save this as a draft, any solution thanks

First thing I noticed is you’re assigning but not using htmlEntity.

@DennisHackethal i have updated my code can you pls check how to pass attachment url

The attachments are just another part in the multipart message payload. The mimemessage node module allows you to add attachments in the same way as other  message body parts (like the htmlEntity and plainEntity in your example). You'd additionally need to add a Content-Disposition header with value as attachment; filename=<name of file>. Take a look at the example in the Usage Example section of the module readme.
Please note that the body field in the attachment 'part' would need to be base64 encoded string. In NodeJS you can read a file as base64 string using something like this:
const { readFile } = require('fs/promise');

// ...
const imageBuf = await readFile(filename);
const attachmentEntity = mimemessage. factory({
    contentType: 'image/png',
    contentTransferEncoding: 'base64',
    body: imageBuf.toString('base64')
});
attachmentEntity.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment ;filename="image.png"');



Thanks if i need to give path only is this correct : const attachmentEntity = mimemessage.factory({          contentType: 'image/png',  body: 'https://XXXXX.PNG'  }); is this correct
